# Web Essentials output different when compiled on different computers

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

When i compile my websolution, web essentials generates css files out of the less files. 
I get always sourecontrol conflicts, because the output of the css files is different. 
The output genereated with vs2013/webessentials on a computer of a team mate is different than on my computer.

e.g. On his computer, a less color variable which is written as name(e.g. red), is compiled into the css as 'red'
On my computerr, the same variable is compiled as rgb value.

[image]

Another sample is comments which exist on my colleagues output, but not on mine. 
[image]

We both use the same setup

- Visual Studio 2013, update 4
- Web Essentials 2013 Update 4, Version 2.5.3
- We use the same WebEssentials-Settings.json
- We have the same settings under 'Tools/Options/Web Essentials'

Question:
What could be a reason for such differences in the output css files?

Comment: It looks like your team mate has upgraded his Less compiler to v2.x while you're still using 1.x.

Comment: This is possible, but since we are using the same version of webessentials it seemed to be unlikely. Where do i see which version of the less compiler is used?

Comment: Web Essentials uses `node` installation with the standard Less compiler (`lessc`) and it can be installed/configured/updated independently of WE. Find where WE installs it (path should be in some config files) and check `lessc --version` to make sure.

Comment: You were right. It seems web essentials has mixed up the versions. We both had 2.5.3, but they are different. Here are some more infos: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: How can i now give you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just summarizing comments above):

It looks like your team mate has upgraded his Less compiler to v2.x while you're still using 1.x (that color names thing is one of those minor language changes in v2)

Web Essentials uses plain `node` installation with the standard Less compiler (`lessc`) and it can be installed/configured/updated independently of WE. Find where WE installs it (path should be in some config files) and check `lessc --version` to make sure.